# C# - GetMemberBinder split

Tags: c#, dynamicobject

I have a setting file that is formatted like so:

```
[Database]
Host=localhost
Username=root
Password=root
```

Now, I have a class named `Settings` which is a `DynamicObject` so I can use dynamic settings. When I parse the file, the key for the dictionary that contains the settings is the header + key. So, for example, the key in the `Host` case would be `Database.Host` and the value would be `localhost`.

Now, I want the user to use it like so:

```
dynamic settings = new Settings("Config.ini");

string host = settings.Database.Host;
```

However, when I override `TryGetMember`, `GetMemberBinder` only contains `Name`, and the `Name` is Database and not Database.Host as it should be. How can I "split" the `GetMemberBinder` `Name` property? When I use `.` the `Name` property doesn't contain what's after the `.`.

**For example**,

when I use:

```
settings.Database.Host
```

then

`GetBinderName` `Name` only contains Database, but it should contain:

Database.Host.

Thanks.

**EDIT: ** I have another question. Let's say I have string name = "Database", and then I do settings.Name.Host. It doesn't resolve Name as Database. Is there a solution to it?

Answer (score 0):

settings.Database is an object not a dynamic, you have no control over it.
Writing settings.Database_Host is a simple solution even not so beatiful than settings.Database.Host.

If you don't know the section, only the property, you can still "cheat" in your resolver: if the property starts with a special string (e.g. __) it means to search for all section:
settings.__Host should find Host entry's value under [Database] or [Server] or any other place. You can even return string[] in TryGetMember in this case instead of the first match if you wish.

Comment: I have another question. Let's say I have string name = "Database", and then I do settings.Name.Host. It doesn't resolve Name as Database. Is there a solution to it?